# How can I delete files or folders created by Nano editor?

Tags: brightness, text-editor, nano

I've searched a method to change the brightness of my laptop display. I saw one article on this forum and followed the instruction like below (under the line) written by Serge (user name).

I ran command line `sudo nano brightness` and when editor popped up I typed 100 and hit the new. However, the brightness didn't get changed even though I restarted the laptop. So I gave up changing setting.

Then, I want to delete the setting, file or folder that I created(?) using nano which I typed 100 in it. How can I do this?

---

Now we can edit brightness file to actually change screen brightness.
We will need some text editor command. I prefer using command line
text editor nano. So I would do

```
sudo nano brightness
```

It will ask you for your password. Enter it, and you will see another screen. Look at where your cursoris, right after the number. That's what I
mean when I said "*don't hit enter*".

This file has to have only that one line, no other. You can use <kbd>left</kbd> / <kbd>right</kbd> keys to move cursor, and <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>del</kbd> keys to delete old number, and then type new.
Remember, that you can only go from whatever number was in
max_brightness file to 0.

When you wrote new number, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, it will ask if you want to "Save modified buffer". Press <kbd>Y</kbd>. Then it will asks what name of the file to write. Just press <kbd>enter</kbd>, we do not want to change name of this file. Done. At this point your brightness should change.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com! There are a couple of things missing from this question. If you simply want to delete the file called `brightness` then `rm brightness` would be the correct command. But please edit your question and include a link to the original answer by Serge: simply creating a file called `brightness` will not alter the brightness.

Answer (score 3):

The file "brightness" is on a pseudo file system used by the kernel.

See [Why are these directories called file systems?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64007/why-are-these-directories-called-file-systems)

The general location is `/sys/class/backlight/` , although the exact location varies by graphics card.

Example - `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

You can not delete these files.

There are many ways to adjust brightness, but of them I would not use nano.

See [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

Personally I a script and invoke the script as sudo or you can simply

```
echo 10 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/.../brightness
```

The "..." varies with video card and driver, you will need to adjust the path an necessary.

For example, using an Intel GMA500 (my favorite card ;p)

- Poulsbo driver (closed source) path is `/sys/class/backlight/psblvds/brightness`
- Open source (kernel) driver path is `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Note: depending on the card there may be a fix, see also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

Comment: The "..." varies by video card and driver. In the example I posted it was "intel_backlilght" for a path of `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` but the path for an ATI or other video card and driver varies. For example, with an intel GMA500 it is ` /sys/class/backlight/psblvds/brightness` with the Poulsbo driver, and ` /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` using the open source driver.